# how can I draw a real time plot by qt?

Tags: qt, plot, real-time, qwt, qcustomplot

I'm beginner and try to use QCustopPlot.
I want to draw a real time chart.
I use this example code.
but I have so many questions:

1) how can I fixed yAxis to a specific int number (0 to 50)

2) how can I fixed xAxis? I mean I want to have a chart that in passing time, the plot moves. (not the xAxis or yAxis)

sory for my bad language.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these three links should help.

```
void QCPAxis::setRange ( double  lower, double  upper  )
```

http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html#a57d6ee9e9009fe88cb19db476ec70bca

```
void QCPAxis::moveRange ( double  diff)
```

http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html#a18f3a68f2b691af1fd34b6593c886630

> `QCPAxis` Class Reference.
>   Manages a single axis inside a
>   QCustomPlot.

http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html#details

Very similar functions exist in QWT, also.

the `cpuplot` example in QWT shows a scrolling realtime example.  There isn't an online link that I can find for the examples, so you should download it and open the examples after you build it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you. I searched but I couldn't find a good link to download qwt. Do you have any download link for that?

Comment: and it seems that qwt is more difficult than qCustomPlot. Is it true?

Comment: and for the first one, my yAxis shows so many numbers that they are to near together and so unclear.
can I change yAxiss which just show me special numbers? (not all the numbers between 0 to 50)

Comment: Qwt has been around longer, and has a more open license for commercial projects.  Qt Charts is the Qt/Digia Commerical version that is supposed to be the easiest.  I've used Qwt a few different times now and it works well without too much headache.

Comment: does cpuplot qwt example, show the cpu usage (percentage)?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/files/latest/download And here is blog post I put together a while ago related to Qwt and Windows. http://phyatt.t15.org/wp/2015/07/qwt-windows-qtdesigner/ And here is what I thought was a generic Qwt example. https://github.com/peteristhegreat/qwt_generic

Comment: All the images for qwt's screenshots come from their examples.  Build and run all the examples in Qwt and you should have plenty to study to try to figure out how to do what you want to do.

Comment: for the first link, I get the following error:
"The requested URL could not be retrieved"
It's not work for me!!!